# How to remove line coming start to end of graph in PowerBI line chart

Tags: powerbi

I'm relatively new to PowerBI,

I build a report to show the evolution of different values over the last 30 days based on historic data I pull from an Excel file. Configuration-wise all my data is on the *Values* section of the line chart with the only exception of my **Date** field which is on the *Axis* section.

[image]

On the *FILTERS* section, I filtered the data to show only the last 30 days using the *relative date filtering*. This is basically the only filter I'm using. The issue is that the chart is showing a straight line from start to end of each one of the graph, and that for each data value...

[image]

Can you please help me understand which might be the issue and how to solve it ?

I think it might be related to the fact that my historic data is coming from an Excel Table that is being filled automatically over time, and importing the data into PowerBI makes lots of empty values on the table. I have tried filtering the data to exclude the empty values both on the table view and on the *FILTERS* section, but that has failed to solve the issue.

EDIT (21.04.2020 - adding data)

**PowerBI** screenshot: beginning of data
[image]

**PowerBI** screenshot: end of data (239 rows - all distinct values)
[image]

Y

Comment: Please show us your relevant data of the table/columns so we can help you

Comment: Here you have it @Aldert. Thanks in advance for your help !

Comment: Do I understand you map columns to legend? I would have expected a kind of category column with value "Hazmat", "Clothing", etc. could you try to convert the table? I can have a look tomorrow..